# How to force interface builder (storyboard) to generate controller initialisation code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I am getting incredibly frustrated with interface builder at the moment, and would appreciate some help before I ragequit it and code everything by hand (which seems to be much, much, much easier).

The basic situation is this: I need to make a model variable accessible to each view controller in my application.

The simplest way I can see to do this is to just create a property on the view controllers that retains the model, and to set that after the controller is initialised.

However, I can't find any of the actual initialisation code for the views shown on the storyboard in my project.  There's no reference to any of them at all.  Does the interface builder really generate not generate any code reference to its controllers in the app delegate?

For that matter, why is there no reference to any of the top level controller objects (tabview, tableview etc) in code at all?

All I want to know is how to force xcode to actually generate the controller creation code in AppDelegate.m - so that I have access to the created instance of the controller - or, failing that, a way to share the model between these amorphous objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to create a singleton class where you can store all your global variables and methods. Example [here](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually create a subclass of your view controller and then override the methods you want to inject code into. In Interface Builder you can then choose to make your View controllers of this custom type.